# Centering VBox inside Border Pane Layout

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem situating my scene on center in VBox Layout.

I use Border Layout as main, and Vbox is a child of Border Layout.

Any advice is appriciated, thanks!

```
VBox vbox = new VBox();
Scene scenehbox = new Scene(vbox, 200, 200);
vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:DIMGREY");
vbox.getChildren().addAll(username, txuser, password, txpassword, btn1);

primaryStage.setResizable(false);                                      //settings
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setTitle("ROXXY");

root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:DIMGREY");
root.getChildren().addAll(poly, poly2, poly3, poly4, text, vbox);
vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
primaryStage.show();
```

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
 }
```

Comment: You cannot use `vbox` as root of `scenehbox` and as child of `root`. Furthermore assuming `root` is a `BorderPane`: `BorderPane` doesn't really work unless you use the `top`, `center`, ect. properties to add the child.

Answer (score 2):

I think your content is centered. It's just your VBox is growing just enough to contain your elements, therefore you cannot notice the elements being centered on it because there's no space left to be centered on.

Try to set the values of height/width of your VBox or bind them to the size of another element if that's what you are looking for.